# Is 3-space indentation required in reST?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I'm documenting my Python code using Sphinx, and read [in the Python developer's guide](https://devguide.python.org/documenting/#style-guide) (and I think elsewhere as well) that reST files use an indentation of 3 spaces:

> All reST files use an indentation of 3 spaces; no tabs are allowed.

This is the case for the example I copied for my index file, and some other files where my IDE picked up the 3-space indentation and used it for the whole page. The `sphinx-apidoc` extension also uses 3 spaces for the `modules.rst` file it builds.

On the other hand, because Python uses 4-space indentation, all my docstrings are indented with 4 spaces. Moreover the `.. automodule::` directives generated by `sphinx-apidox` are indented with 4 spaces.

The point is, it all still *works*! So I'm left wondering whether the 3-space indentation thing is a requirement, or if it's good practice, but only in terms of style? (And if so, why, when all things Python are 4-space indented?)

Or are there cases where not having 3-space indentation will break my build?

### Other places I've looked

- The [Sphinx reStructuredText Primer](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/rest.html#rst-primer) doesn't mention a specific number of spaces, only:

  > As in Python, indentation is significant in reST, so all lines of the same paragraph must be left-aligned to the same level of indentation.
- This [(unanswered) SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18876046/how-can-i-change-the-default-indentation-in-sphinx), which is about lists specifically, not spacing generally
- The [reStructuredText Markup Specification](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#indentation) only mentions 3 spaces in reference to [footnotes](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#footnotes).
- This [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/benoitbryon/documentation-style-guide-sphinx/issues/9), though I *think* this issue here is the mixture of indentation levels for different elements.

---

I'm beginning to think the Python developer's guide might be the anomaly, rather than everything else, especially since in all my searching I've come across basically no discussion of the "3-or-4 space problem" when working with Sphinx and Python.

Comment: The 3-space rule you're citing is from a style guide. It's one project's style rule.

Comment: Okay, so is the "project" here official Python documentation? As in, it's the style guide for documentation on docs.python.org?

Comment: Yes. You're reading the guide for developers working on Python itself.

Comment: I have found (by trial and error due to lack of strict specification) that directives with content require content to be indented by exactly 3 spaces. 2 spaces and content is not recognized as a part of the directive; 4 spaces and content is treated as if every line started with a space. This is really annoying for `code` and other text-display directives because stuff itself has 4-space indent while beginning indent must be 3.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As you have found through your research of the authoritative source and elsewhere, there is no definitive indentation specification, except a minimum of 2 spaces for option lists, and a minimum of 3 spaces for footnotes. See the [specification on indentation for reStructuredText](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/docs/ref/rst/restructuredtext.html#indentation).

That said, there are some recommendations.

1. Choose a style and keep it consistent for your documentation.
2. IDEs often complain about incorrect indentation, like for docstrings in Python, so using 4 spaces can avoid those warnings.
3. IDEs can be set to indent to 4 spaces for code, so why not keep it the same for documentation?
4. See my [bonus tip about indenting for numbered lists](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45683081/2214933).

Comment: I know the advice says to "avoid comments like 'thanks' ", but this is my first SO question, so...thanks for the advice, and that bonus tip for numbered lists is great! (I appreciate that it both makes working with 4-space indents easier, and gives consistency to the look for no.s 10-99)