# RestructuredText lists wrap unexpectedly

Tags: list, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I'm trying to make lists in Sphinx. However, they end up broken like so [here](https://qgis-tuts-wu.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/land_degradation_development/interpolation/interpolation.html#spline-interpolation):
where the input code is:
[image: broken list]

```
#. Set the :guilabel:`Output extent [optional] to
   :menuselection:`... --> Calculate from Layer --> Reprojected`
#. for :guilabel:`Cellsize` enter :file:`1970`
```

However, on other occasions it just works normally. Just to be sure:

```
This is unrelated text that needs a full line after

#. Then now we start a numbered list
#. If you have a line that is really long and
   needs to be split over different lines, you
   can do that by indenting
#. You can also have different paragraphs

   like this inside a list. Be aware that it should be 
   indented and there should be a whitespace after

#. Then this item will render correctly

An unindented paragraph will re-set the list

#. this item starts at 1 again
```

It seems really random to me. Maybe something with the type of line ending (CRLF/LF) number of spaces in indents?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out to be the number of spaces. Very confusingly, this is also different for a numbered (3: `#.` /`1.` ) or bullet (2:`*` ) list. For example this is correct:

```
This is unrelated text that needs a full line after

#. Then now we start a numbered list
#. If you have a line that is really long and
   needs to be split over different lines, you
   can do that by indenting
#. You can also have different paragraphs

   like this inside a list. Be aware that it should be 
   indented and there should be a whitespace after

   * You need whitespace for a bulletlist
   * and then if you have a really long item, that
     is split along multiple lines, make sure that in 
     this case you have 2 (two) spaces

   #. But, then again if you would have a numbered list
      that is split over multiple lines, you need to enter
      3 (three) spaces.
   #. and it continues to the next point
   #. but this is confusing
   #. also logical in another way

#. Then this item will render correctly

an unindented parargaph in between will terminate the list
```

This finally renders correctly:

[image: success!]

Comment: Bonus tip, just use 4 spaces for all indentation. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/48313531/2214933

Comment: @StevePiercy I was working on documentation that was already using the 3-space (2-space) indentation, so then 4-space indentation started doing weird things like above. Correcting from 4-space to 3-space solved this. For future projects I will consider!