# Nested sub-list in reStructuredText with code blocks not working

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I'm using sphinx to try and create HTML documents from .rst files.  I'm attempting to create a document that has a numbered list (1., 2., ...) , with a nested sub-list (a., b, c., ...) that shows example code.  But I'm having trouble teasing out the syntax to get the nested sub-list to work.  Here's an example `.rst` file of what I've tried:

```
===========
Tester Page
===========

Below are some test paragraphs.

1. This is a paragraph detailing a higher level step, with 3 sub-steps.
 a. This is a sub-bullet, with an example:
::

    ls -l foo.txt

 b. I can't get this line to not display as part of the code block! This is another sub-bullet, with an example:
::

    git add bar.txt

2. This is step 2.

This is the end of the document.
```

The above gives me a result similar to this (hard to reproduce exactly in Markdown, but hopefully you get the idea):

> ## Tester Page
>
> Below are some test paragraphs.
>
> 1. This is some text.
>
>    a. This is a sub-bullet, with an example:

```
  ls -l foo.txt

b. This is another sub-bullet, with an example:
  git add bar.txt
```

> 2. This is step 2.
>
> This is the end of the document.

I've been tweaking double-colons, white-space, and back-quotes for at least an hour, and can't figure out how to get it to format correctly.  Perhaps reStructuredText is just not quite versatile enough to handle the nested list with embedded code blocks?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have to be very careful with both vertical and horizontal whitespace. Nested lists must be separated from the parent list items by a blank line. Code examples in literal blocks must be indented properly.

```
Below are some test paragraphs.

1. This is a paragraph detailing a higher level step, with 3 sub-steps.

   a. This is a sub-bullet, with an example::

         ls -l foo.txt

   b. I can get this line to display as part of the code block!
      This is another sub-bullet, with an example::

         git add bar.txt

2. This is step 2.
```

Comment: Ok, this got me to the solution I needed!  In summary: blank lines should be *empty* blank lines (watch out for editors like TextPad and Eclipse that auto-indent and leave spaces)!  Also, 3 spaces extra indent seems to be the magic number.  Make sure all your items are vertically aligned, and if in doubt, indent more!  That worked for me.

Comment: @OgrePsalm33 3 spaces is not a requirement, and could be hindrance with your editor. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/48313531/2214933 and my [Bonus Tip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45681920/end-literal-block-in-list-item/45683081#45683081)

Comment: I wonder if the same applies to `code-block` within a quote? I tried quite hard on [this one](https://shorturl.at/hjlI8) but I can't figure out what the rule is.

Comment: If the problem is different I should probably open a new question.

Comment: Ah never mind, I found the issue, I had an invisible character messing with my code. [Fixed it](https://shorturl.at/mDSWZ)