# Sphinx literal block and csv-table within list item

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I have a numbered list where some items contain both a literal block (`::`) and a `csv-table`:

```
1. Table number 1::

    *A literal note about table 1

.. csv-table::
   :file: table1_example.csv
```

This renders the table at the same indentation level as the list numbers (not indented). Because the `csv-table` is only relevant to list item #1, I would like it to appear indented to the same level as the list contents (one tab indented). I have tried different combinations of the literal block and directive to no avail:

```
1. Table number 1::

    *A literal note about table 1


    .. csv-table::
       :file: table1_example.csv
```

includes the `csv-table` in the literal block;

```
1. Table number 1:
    
    .. csv-table::
       :file: table1_example.csv

    ::
        *A literal note about table 1
```

and

```
1. Table number 1:
    
    .. csv-table::
       :file: table1_example.csv::
        
    *A literal note about table 1
```

don't render the literal block at all.
Is there any way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/45683081/407651

Comment: @mzjn Thank you, it was the spaces.